# Set listview items with a specific height

Tags: android, xml, listview, height

I want to adjust the items in a listview with a specific height.

[image]

The adapter I do: *?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight*, which works well when the height of the listview is *fill_parent*.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FirstText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="12dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:divider="#4436f2"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>
```

But when the height of the listview is a specific size does not fit the items.

[image]

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200sp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:divider="#4436f2"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>
```

How I can adjust the height of items with a specific listview?

Comment: how you setup your adapter for the list view? what parameters are you using in the setAdapter() method?

Comment: your up n down buttons are out of list?

Comment: So you want to adjust the items so that they all fit with the given height of the listview?

Comment: I assume these are header and footer for the list and are static. Basically there's parameter for the `...setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,....))` which sets the style of your listview items and/or you set your item styles in the getView() of your custom adapter and describe your item_row as an xml and then inflate it in the getView() again.

Comment: I want to set the items to a list with padding. The list has an adapter.

Comment: so in your custom adapter you have your getView() where you inflate your item/row xml. in which you describe your textviews and so on so this is basically where you do it. Like here for example https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Custom Adapter there u can do what ever u want

Comment: Can you add more details? As it is this doesn't explain much.

Comment: We prefer that you put information in the post, so that if the link ever goes dead the information is still available.

Comment: I actually have no knowledge of this particular domain, but these rules apply regardless.

Comment: I'm using a listview with adapter, but I can not set the listview items to use as padding